# What are cross-browser and cross-OS safe keyboard shortcuts usable for web application?

Tags: web-applications, hotkeys

I am developing a quite large web application, and it is probably a good idea to use hotkeys for some common tasks. However, I discovered that finding safe key combinations is a problem, regarding all different browsers and OSes.

For example, Chrome has such a long list of hotkeys that trying to use some kind of logical hotkeys scheme for my web application is impossible - e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, etc.

Do you have some cheat sheet of safe hotkeys which can be used in a web application and not worry about some browser or OS interference?

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to post a link to Microsoft's site with common used hotkeys in their OSes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wouldn't count on it.  It's probably okay to listen for shortcuts that use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier, but there's still no way to be sure a keyboard shortcut is free. Users can always install programs that listen for keyboard shortcuts, or use a browser you didn't expect.

If the shortcuts can be used only when the user is not typing in a textbox or something, it might be a better idea to just listen for keys pressed without a modifier key.

If no textbox or other GUI element is focused, then `document.activeElement == document.body` should be true (somebody correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: "It's probably okay to listen for shortcuts that use the Alt modifier" Nope, there are many Alt keyboard shortcuts in Chrome. For example, Alt+d is address bar, Alt+f is the settings drop-down. Here are all of them: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there is such a list. This may even be different for different locales.

You can try to rely on the accesskey feature of HTML: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accesskey. This should keep the number of collisions relatively small. Though I believe the Windows browsers will offer these keys as Alt+Letter which collides with the menu bar.

Alternatively do what Google reader and Gmail do: use the letters directly without any hotkey modifier. That will only work for certain types of applications, though.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Problem is that most of the functionality with hotkeys happens in textbox, so accesskey is useless in this case.

User enters shop items in a form, and right now I am using for example ctrl+enter as a shortcut to add shop item or ctrl+f1 to lookup item using ajax to see if it already exists, and so on....

I spend some time googling on this and I think there really isn't list of generally available hotkeys for web apps. I just thought someone here could have made one for him or herself.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook uses the following ones that need different main keys to press depending on the used browser:

https://www.facebook.com/help/156151771119453?helpref=faq_content

```
Key Combinations for Different Browsers

Find the right combination of keys for your browser in the list below, and replace # with the access key number listed under access keys below.

Internet Explorer for PC: Alt + #, then Enter
Firefox for PC: Shift + Alt + #
Safari for Mac: Ctrl + Opt + #
Firefox for Mac: Ctrl + Opt + #
Chrome for Mac: Ctrl + Opt + #
Chrome for PC: Alt + #

Access keys
0 - Help
1 - Home
2 - Timeline
3 - Friends
4 - Inbox
5 – Notifications
6 – Settings
7 - Activity Log
8 - About
9 - Terms
```

However, Facebook supports these shortcuts in all browsers:

```
Web Messenger Keyboard Shortcuts
Ctrl + G - Search conversations
Ctrl + Q - Show/hide keyboard shortcuts
Ctrl + Delete - Archive/unarchive conversation
Ctrl + J - Mark as spam
Ctrl + M - Start a new message
Ctrl + I - Go to Inbox
Ctrl + U - Go to Other
```

Conclusion: Some shortcuts might work in all browsers, but most of them need additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As with most lists, it is easier to list (and therefore find) what exists rather than what is available. Depending on how you define "safe hotkey" there are quite a few (the basic ones), or thousands (slightly more advanced ones, like how Gmail uses two letter combinations (hotstrings)).

I think the best you can do is to look at these two comprehensive lists for [OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) and [browser](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm) specific hotkeys, and make a list based on those. If you want to take it one step further, [here is something that might help you (not tested it myself)](http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/).

For your specific issue I think you should look at how Gmail, Facebook, Remember the Milk uses hotkeys; as these all have solved your issue elegantly. If you make a list of what they use you might have a list of hotkeys to use there. On a side note, I use Breevy, AutoHotkey, and several other programs that I create the advanced type of hotkeys (43,956 and counting), and because their are the simple kind, there was hardly ever an issue with overlapping hotkeys with their systems.

Answer (score 1):

In short: **No**.

Suggested modifier keys (the other modifier keys are used by OS or browser):

- macOS - <kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>
- win OS - just <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>
- you can use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> on macOS, which is similar to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> on win