# What keyboard shortcut can i use without conflicts with modern browsers?

Tags: web, cross-browser, keyboard-shortcuts, compatibility, shortcut

I'm developping a web application and i intend to use mouse and some keyboard shortcuts, and if possible, use modal keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

I've noticed a lot a conflicts with modern browsers/OS. Here are some examples you may know:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> : refreshes the page on firefox
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+*left click* : moves a window on linux
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> : opens the download tab in chrome

I can't find what shortcuts (with modal keys) i can use **safely** in my application. Is there a list somewhere of a rule to follow?

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at [this](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm), which is a rather exhaustive list of used shortcuts.

However your question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941180/available-keyboard-shortcuts-for-web-applications) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329420/what-are-cross-browser-cross-os-safe-keyboard-shortcuts-usable-for-web-applica) and it seems there is no such list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts

My suggestion would to throw something unique in the shortcut for example:

Say you needed to bookmark something quickly, chromes is ctrl+D, instead i would do ctrl+shift+m  or ctrl+alt+m

Even still you might run into duplicate shortcuts, but going with something unique will give you the best results.

Hope this helps.